# Matrix 2.5.3 thousands_sep and decimals

Tags: matrix

I updated to matrix 2.5.3 from version 2.4.3 on my mamp test setup and notice the following issues.

On the prior version matrix was outputting prices using a comma for the thousands_sep parameter. The new version of matrix no longer outputs the comma and in addition, adds decimal places:

**Version 2.4.3 output**: $279,950

**Version 2.5.3 output**: $279950.00

I notice the decimal settings now in the matrix field setup which I've used to remove the decimal places. However, I cannot find a way to get matrix 2.5.3 to use the thousands_sep as it was previously. Any solutions?

Here is the code, which did not change. neighborhood_plan_price is the variable in question:

```
                    <tbody>
                    {exp:channel:entries channel="neighborhood" dynamic="no" sort="asc" orderby="neighborhood_city" status="Not Closed" disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination"}
                    <tr url="{path='neighborhood-detail/{url_title}'}">
                        <td><a href="{path='neighborhood-detail/{url_title}'}">{title}</a></td>
                        <td>{neighborhood_city}, {neighborhood_state}</td>
                                {if status == "Coming Soon"}
                                <td>Coming soon</td>
                                {if:elseif status == "Sold Out"}
                                <td>Sold Out</td>
                                {if:else}
                                <td class="dollar">{neighborhood_plans limit="1"}{neighborhood_plan_price}{/neighborhood_plans}</td>
                                {/if}
                    </tr>
                    {/exp:channel:entries}  
                </tbody>
```

[image: Matrix field setup in version 2.5.3]

Comment: Hey Stephen - could you add some context to your post with a screenshot of your Matrix settings, as well as your template code?  Thank you!

Comment: Code and screenshot added.

Comment: Alright. What are you entering on the publish screen, Stephen? Exactly so I can copy/paste it. I tried a variety of combinations of your number and get a variety of errors back so I can't reproduce your exact issue.

Comment: Whoops, left that detail out. In the publish screen 279950 is entered. No decimals, commas or dollar sign. Just the number digits.

Comment: Alright.  I got ya.  When I output this in the template I Just get the straight number, no formatting at all.  I can't get the parameter to ouptut much at all for that, comma or not.  Let me investigate further.  Thank you Stephen!

Comment: Hi Lisa, any update on this issue?

Comment: I've reported it as a bug, no updates yet.  I'll follow up and get back to you shortly

Comment: Hi Lisa, checking in again on this. Any update?

Comment: Not yet, Stephen, but I've requested an update. :)

Comment: Lisa, I see these features were restored with Matrix 2.5.5 released today. I've installed it to test and there's a new bug. If you set the decimal place to none, from say, 2, matrix will actually update the channel entry data!

Comment: To be clear, matrix will round up the entry value based upon the decimal settings and replace it in the database. It will round 2.5 to 3. If you change the decimal places back to 2, you won't get the original 2.5, you'll get 3.